# Can actionscript 3 bubbling work for custom event and object hierarchy?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have searched on the Internet and didn't find any clue on how to do so, any idea ? I don't want flex only flash (my objects are not visual components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic and unfinished custom event class that supports bubbling.
You will also notice I added an additional parameter for an object so I could pass along data.
Also note that custom event classes need a clone method if the event dispatched event is re-dispatched.
For example if a callback function from the custom event then re-dispatches the event the clone method will make a copy of the event for the new dispatcher.


I also want to add I never had a need to use the bubbling aspect of this class so it is, well, untested.

```
// ActionScript file
package events{
  import flash.events.Event;    
  public class DynamicEvent extends Event{
  public var data:Object;
  private var _type:String;
  private var _bubbles:Boolean; 
  private var _cancelable:Boolean;
    public function DynamicEvent( oData:Object, sType:String, bBubbles:Boolean = false,  bCancelable:Boolean = false):void{
      super(sType, bBubbles, bCancelable);
      this.data = oData;
      this._type = sType;
      this._bubbles = bBubbles;
      this._cancelable = bCancelable;
    }
    public override function clone():Event{
      return new DynamicEvent(this.data, this._type, this._bubbles, this._cancelable );
    }
    public override function get type():String{
      return this._type;
    }
    public function set type( sType:String ):void{
      this._type = sType;
    }
    public override function get bubbles():Boolean{
      return this._bubbles;
    }
    public function set bubbles( bBubbles:Boolean ):void{
      this._bubbles = bBubbles;
    }
    public override  function get cancelable():Boolean{
      return this._cancelable;
    }
    public function set cancelable( bCancelable:Boolean ):void{
      this._cancelable = bCancelable;
    }
  }
}
```

[EDIT]

```
//usage to dispatch
var e:DynamicEvent = new DynamicEvent( {anyAttributeYouWantToCallIt:"someDataHere"}, "YourEventNameHere" );
this.dispatchEvent(e);

// usage to listen
ObjectDispatchingCustomEvent.addEventListener( 'YourEventNameHere, callBackFunc' )

//call back function
public function callBackFunc( e:DynamicEvent ):void{
   trace( e.data.anyAttributeYouWantToCallIt ) // will show someDataHere
}
```

Comment: Good starting point, could you give an example of how I would use it ?

Comment: You don't have to override any of those methods but clone.

Comment: Probably not, when I created this I got it working for what I needed and never bothered to put more effort into it. But I vaguely remember getting compile errors without overriding the getters. One day I will have to finish this up

Answer (score 3):

Event bubbling really only works in a `DisplayObject` hierarchy, and for custom events it only works in a limited way.

### Think of it this way:

A display object has a parent (with the exception of the stage). If you have a child dispatch an event, it makes sense that that could be relevant to anything which contains it. If I have a component with a special button which dispatches the "foo" event, I will be listening to the component, even though the button dispatched the event.

On the other hand, generic `IEventDispatcher`s don't have the parent relationship. If I have a custom data object, and another object which happens to be a property on that object dispatches an event, then it does not make sense to have the container dispatch an event (unless specifically told to). Heck, the containing object might not even know that the contained object is a dispatcher! In addition to this, if a container dispatched every time that a private property dispatched, that would, in very short order, lead to recursive event dispatching and the dreaded stack overflow.

### But why did I say that it is limited?

MouseEvents bubble. That is clear. But custom events often do not bubble in the same way that MouseEvents do. When a MouseEvent bubbles it has two phases, a capture phase and a non-capture (? not sure what that's actually called) phase. The capture phase starts at the `root` and works its way into the actual dispatching `DisplayObject` whereas the other phase starts at the `DisplayObject` and then works its way to the `root`.

I have often found that the capture phase is omitted when dispatching an event from a custom component. This doesn't normally matter in the slightest, but it does effect the odd corner case, so it is good to watch out for.

Comment: +1 ... hoping future versions of actionscript will support bubbling in a more robust way (for example = limiting to display objects is a real issue, sometimes).

Comment: @Bosworth99 I actually think that this is one of the best ways that it can manage things. If bubbling equivalents are needed, they can still be created on a case-by-case basis, but I have nightmares of infinite recursion. What I really want is for bubbling to be consistent with custom events.

Comment: Just want to point out an event has 3 phases bubble,capture, and target. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html

Comment: @The_asMan I've always viewed "target" as the first part of the bubbling phase. I suppose that technically that isn't accurate, but in practical purposes...

Comment: "If bubbling equivalents are needed, they can still be created on a case-by-case basis, but I have nightmares of infinite recursion." At present, this seems to be quite hard.  It would be useful if Event had a method 'getNextBubbleTarget' or similar that you could override to change the bubbling heirarchy.  By default, it would return the current target's container if the current target is a display object in the display list, or null otherwise.  But then anyone could override it and have events bubble as required.  And a capture phase for custom events could be implemented similarly.

Answer (score 3):

Event bubbling only really makes sense in the context of the display tree, because there is a clear hierarchy established already. If you want to pass messages between a large number of non-display objects, you're better off using an event hub model. I.E. - routing events with application-wide importance through a static event dispatcher:

```
package {
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    public class EventHub {
        public static const dispatcher : EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    }
}
```

Then, all the objects (both display and non-display) in your app that need notification can work through EventHub.dispatcher:

```
EventHub.dispatcher.addEventListener(MyCustomEvent.TYPE, myHandlerFunction);

EventHub.dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new MyCustomEvent(MyCustomEvent.TYPE, ...));
```

Comment: I have my own hierarchy of objects so my question. I'm not interested in display objects only. I can't find any reason except commercial one why the bubbling framework is not made available to client. Otherwise I need to build it from scratch (using your code as starting point probably but dealing with a whole hierarchy may not be obvious).